# ModelBuilder summary statistics for one shapefile produced from clip iteration?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm very new to ModelBuilder and trying to build a tool which clips 4 national data sets to a study area defined as a local authority. There is a points dataset containing population data, local authority boundaries and flood extents.  Ultimately the output I am after is a summary statistics showing the population within the flood extents for that study area.  I've managed to get the first part working where the user selects a local authority from a drop down list and the data is clipped to this study area through a feature class iterator.  This is a sub-model within my main model.  I then want to perform separate geoprocessing on each of the clipped feature classes, and this is the part I can't get working.  I need to work with the results of my sub-model, and produce summary statistics where the population points are within the flood extents.  However I can't seem to select the feature class to work with from the output values of my sub-model.  I've attached an image of my model for reference.

[image: Sub Model]
[image]

Comment: My first thought is to Identity or Intersect rather than clip, that way the polygon the points reside in are permanently (until removed) associated with the points... select where the overlapping FID > 0 to restrict or add a case field of polygon ID to the summary statistics then remove the non-overlapping row from the summary table. My second thought is wouldn't this be easier in python?

Comment: Pythons not really an option for me, as I need to create this within ModelBuilder.  Essentially I need to do some geoprocessing on the outputs of an iterative model. I would have thought this would be very simple to implement.  Am I missing a step between the collect values and select data tools?

Comment: Thanks - I've been experimenting with calculate values and using some python script to try and pull the shape files through.  Having more joy

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you have enough in your comment to post a brief answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the [Collects value tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/collect-values.htm) returns a **LIST** of whatever you are collecting. If you read the Help file for the Select data tool it takes as input a data element, that is what the [syntax table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/select-data.htm#GUID-93BC5AE3-7340-4F49-AC45-2E8143F55AA2) is explaining. You should always read the help file! So you are trying to connect a LIST object to something that is expecting a workspace. That is why your model is failing to connect. You need to get into the habitat of reading the syntax section of the help file this helps you understand what tools expect as input for their parameters and what they output.